# Download Android MyFirstApp files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

Starting an app here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Copying directly from the tutorial and it's full of errors. Even if I copy and paste. Is there a repository where I can view the working files and see if there's anything wrong?

For example, in MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

but it returns:

"View cannot be resolved to type" on line 10
"Multiple Markers at this line: Intent cannot be resolved to type" on line 11
"Multiple Markers at this line: EditText cannot be resolved to a type" on line 12

Then in DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
}
```

and it returns:

"Intent cannot be resolved to type" on line 12
"Multiple Markers at this line: TextView cannot be resolved to a type" on line 16

This is my first app and I figured following the official tutorial would be alright but it's not working. I'm using the latest Eclipse and Andorid SDK (downloaded tonight as a matter of fact.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import it.

On the left-side on eclipse there is an incon with a "X", click on it and select "Import 'XXXX'".

Comment: In Project Explorer? The Icon of MyFirstApp project? There's an Import on right-click but what do you import? I already have the project open and all I get with a few experiments is an overlapping project error.

Comment: There's a light bulb icon with a red X, click on it and Import whatever it asks.

If the light bulb says "Intent cannot be resolved to type", you click on it and then on "Import 'Intent'".

Comment: Ok, that icon. I got it. Nice of them to let me know that in their tutorial. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some places spell it `DisplayMessageActivity`, and others spell it `DisplayMesageActivity`, with only one "s" in message.

Refactor and rename the `DisplayMesageActivity.java` file.